# Adiabatic elimination of "fast"/"velocity" variable

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-approximation

My question comes from section IV, part A of the paper titled [Stochastic resonance](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/pdf/10.1103/RevModPhys.70.223?casa_token=XRG4LcSLZQkAAAAA%3ASSkjjjmqPBZy_SrSu8CpGIpfDBl5sadQLiZaW17qSsnh8OQjIsGWDPt2QN0nF5SjfVWRgz8YOhRsHd4). Specifically, their equation (4.1) states that, if we start with a Langevin equation of the form $$m\ddot{x} = -m\gamma \dot{x} - V'(x) + mA_0\cos(\Omega t + \varphi) + \sqrt{2m\gamma kT}\xi(t),\label{1}\tag{*}$$ where $\xi$ denotes a Gaussian white noise, and $\gamma, k, A_0, T, \Omega, \varphi > 0$ are constant. Then if we write the first order system (in terms of $(x,v=\dot{x})$) corresponding to \eqref{1}, and somehow "eliminate" the velocity (fast) variable, we will end up with the so-called Smoluchowski equation/approximation $$\gamma\dot{x} = -V'(x)/m + A_0\cos(\Omega t + \varphi) + \sqrt{2\gamma D}\xi(t),\label{2}\tag{**}$$ in which $D := kT/m$. Since this is not a consequence of the usual "overdamped limit" (where we take the limit $m \to 0^+$), may I know how does \eqref{2} follow from \eqref{1}? What does the procedure of adiabatic elimination really mean in this specific example?

Comment: in this case the limit procedure is $m\rightarrow 0$, $\gamma,A_0\rightarrow\infty$ at fixed $m\gamma$, $mA_0$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker No, it's not that easy, if you were correct, then $D$ would converge to $\infty$ (because $k$ is the Boltzmann constant, and $T$ is the temperature that is supposed to be fixed...)!

Comment: certainly, $D\rightarrow\infty$, which is what you need in the equation $$\dot{x} = -V'(x)/m\gamma + (A_0/\gamma)\cos(\Omega t + \varphi) + \sqrt{2D/\gamma}\,\xi(t).$$ Since $D/\gamma=kT/m\gamma$ this ratio remains finite when you send $m\rightarrow 0$, $\gamma\rightarrow\infty$ at fixed product $m\gamma$. In the paper you cite they refer to the "large friction limit", which is equivalent to the "small-mass" limit you are referring to, since one should insist on a finite product $m\gamma$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you! I forget that there is a $\gamma$ on the left hand side...